# how to set PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW in request header?

Tags: php, header, httprequest, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I am doing this with PHP and would like to know a way to setup `PHP_AUTH_USER`, `PHP_AUTH_PW`, `HTTP_X_USERNAME`, `HTTP_X_PASSWORD` from request headers.

When I set the request header as:

```
Authorization: Basic myuser:mypass
```

it gives some strange values:

```
[PHP_AUTH_USER] => k
[PHP_AUTH_PW] => �j�����
```

But when i set it this way:

```
Authorization: Basic bXl1c2VyOm15cGFzcw==
```

it returns:

```
[PHP_AUTH_USER] => myuser
[PHP_AUTH_PW] => mypass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Basic` is used for the  `Authorization` header, the authentication information is `username:password` in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

PHP only sets the `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` fields from the `Authorization` field. The `HTTP_X_USERNAME` and `HTTP_X_PASSWORD` fields relate to the `X-Username` and `X-Password` headers (not) sent by the client, ie. PHP sets them if it gets them with the request.

Comment: ok thanks. but why it doesnt give the username and password under these server variables, 'HTTP_X_USERNAME' & 'HTTP_X_PASSWORD' ? is it possible to set value for those to server variables?